# Preencher um Array Multidimensional com Loop a partir de 3 Arrays separados em PHP

Tags: php, array, loop

Algúem sabe uma forma de preencher um Array Multidimensional com uma estrutura de Loop a partir de 3 Arrays separados em PHP?

Os arrays separados estão na seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o preenchimento com alguma estrutura de loop um único array deverá possuir a seguinte estrutura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei com 2 foreach e com 2 for porém nenhum deu certo.

Fico no aguardo.

Comment: Opa Anderson Carlos Woss, essa solução ai serviu, obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, consegui resolver utilizando dois foreach, veja se te ajuda:

```
$dados = [

  'id' => [1,2,3,4],
  'ocorrencia' => [10,13,17,18],
  'justificativa' => ['1232132131','232323232','435454354','565656565']
];


foreach($dados as $chave => $d ){

  //$chave = id, ocorrencia, justificativa

  foreach($d as $indice => $valor){

    //$indice = 0,1,2,3
    //$valor = 10,13,17,18

    /* $novoArray[0][id] = 1;
       $novoArray[1][id] = 2;
       $novoArray[2][id] = 3;
       $novoArray[3][id] = 4;
       $novoArray[0][ocorrencia] = 10;
       $novoArray[1][ocorrencia] = 13;
       $novoArray[2][ocorrencia] = 17; ... E por ai vai */

    $novoArray[$indice][$chave] = $valor; 

   }
}
```

Se quiser testar, basta copiar e colar esse código e jogar aqui no http://phptester.net/